# не запускается web страница после перехода с mustache на freemarker

Tags: java, spring-boot, freemarker

Есть небольшое web-приложение на Spring. решил перейти с mustache на freemarker и теперь не запускается стартовая web-страница - выдает 404
в pom.xml зависимости прописал:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Умные люди советовали переименовать .ftl на .ftlh, или в пропрети добавить spring.freemarker.suffix= .ftl
Ни то, ни другое не помогает.
Вот файл main.ftlh:

```
<#import "parts/common.ftlh" as c>
<#import "parts/login.ftlh" as l>
<@c.page>
<div>
    <@l.logout />
</div>
<div>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Введите сообщение" />
        <input type="text" name="tag" placeholder="Тэг">
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="${_csrf.token}" />
        <button type="submit">Добавить</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div>Список сообщений</div>
<form method="get" action="/main">
    <input type="text" name="filter" value="${filter}">
    <button type="submit">Найти</button>
</form>
<#list messages as message>
<div>
    <b>${message.id}</b>
    <span>${message.text}</span>
    <i>${message.tag}</i>
    <strong>${message.authorName}</strong>
</div>
<#else>
No message
</#list>
</@c.page>
```

Answer (score 0):

404 это ответ сервера (страница не найдена). Это не ошибка шаблонизатора. Проверьте контроллер, в котором указан маппинг на шаблон.

```
@Controller
public class MainController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String  main(Model model) {
        return "MainPage";
    }
}
```

`MainPage` для файла `MainPage.ftlh`

И еще, вроде для работы расширение .ftlh нужна новая версия спринга:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```